# Error on compiling angular 4 module

Tags: angular

I have updated `angular-cli` from `beta.21` to latest and I get error while compiling project: `Calling function 'ApiAuthModule', function calls are not supported`

I think I did move all code to exported functions. What could it be?

Here is my error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ApiAuthModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/strony/www/libsNg/ApiAuth/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/strony/www/libsNg/ApiAuth/src/app/app.module.ts

Here is my `api-auth.module.ts`:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {ApiModule} from "./api/api.module";
import {ApiService} from "./api/api.service";
import {ApiConfig, ApiConfigModel} from "./api/api-config";
import {ResponseHandlerService} from "./response-handler/default/response-handler.service";
import {AuthModule} from "./auth/auth.module";
import {AuthService} from "./auth/auth.service";
import {AuthConfig, AuthHttp} from "angular2-jwt";
import {Http, HttpModule, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        ApiModule,
        AuthModule
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class ApiAuthModule {
    static config: ApiConfigModel;

    static forRoot(config: ApiConfigModel) {
        // static forRoot(config: ApiConfigModel): ModuleWithProviders {
        let responseHandlerClass = config.responseHandlerService || ResponseHandlerService;
        this.config = config;
        return {
            ngModule: ApiAuthModule,
            providers: [
                ApiService,
                AuthService,
                {
                    provide: AuthHttp,
                    useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
                    deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
                },
                // AUTH_PROVIDERS,
                // provideAuth({
                //     // headerName: YOUR_HEADER_NAME,
                //     // headerPrefix: YOUR_HEADER_PREFIX,
                //     tokenName: localStorageTokenId,
                //     tokenGetter: tokenGetterFunc(localStorageTokenId),
                //     // globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
                //     noJwtError: true,
                //     // noTokenScheme: true
                // }),
                {
                    provide: ApiConfig,
                    useFactory: ApiConfigFactory
                },
                {
                    provide: ResponseHandlerService,
                    useClass: responseHandlerClass
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}

export function ApiConfigFactory() {
    // console.log(ApiAuthModule.config);
    return new ApiConfig(ApiAuthModule.config);
}
// export function tokenGetterFunc(localStorageTokenId) {
//     return localStorage.getItem(localStorageTokenId);
// }
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
    let localStorageTokenId = ApiAuthModule.config.localStorageTokenId || 'id_token';
    return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: localStorageTokenId,
        tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem(localStorageTokenId)),
        // tokenName: 'token',
        // tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token')),
    }), http, options);
}
```

And `app.module.ts`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ApiAuthModule} from "./api-auth/api-auth.module";
import {AlertyModule} from "lukana-alerty";
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {ResponseHandlerAlertyService} from "./api-auth/response-handler/alerty/response-handler-status.service";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,

        ApiAuthModule.forRoot({
            baseUrl: 'http://www.system.local/api/',
            authUrl: 'auth/login/',
            responseJsonTokenId: 'token',
            responseHandlerService: ResponseHandlerAlertyService//ResponseHandlerStatusService
        }),
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AlertyModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Please update your Typescript to latest version

Comment: See if it builds with `--aot=false` to start with. If that works, then you will want to read over the guides you can find on the internet about how to get your app to build with AOT.

Comment: I've updated typescript to `2.3.3` - error is there. `ng build --aot=false` - error still there. Wierd thing when `ng serve` I get error but when I change something in code it compiles correctly

Comment: I figured that angular doesn't like `let responseHandlerClass = config.responseHandlerService || ResponseHandlerService;` and `{provide: ResponseHandlerService, useClass: responseHandlerClass}` but have no idea how to fix it